# Is it possible to get the current date in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to store the current date in a column's view  i have and then compare it with a date a user has saved.

Is it possible to get the current date in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: You can't (despite some blog posts saying you can) - but tell us why do you want to do this and there may be another way. Is it for filtering or doing something like a countdown where "You have X days left to complete this" or red flag when something is past its due date.

Comment: I want to compare them in order to change the color of a column [green, yellow or red] to show the progress of a task. I am able to apply the colors i want but i need to make this comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an article on our company blog that outlines the various methods of using [Today] in this context, as well as a little background on why [Today] isn't available in calculated columns:

*Warning: this also contains recommendations for our own product*

[How to use [Today] in a sharepoint list](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-use-today-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

Here are the main methods covered:

- **JavaScript**: Use a Content Editor Web Part
- **Designer**: Create a custom view in SharePoint Designer
- **Code**: Make your own custom field type from scratch
- **SharePoint Highlighter**: Our own solution to the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Today] as a filter in views.  For example, for a task list you could filter overdue tasks by setting a filter "DueDate < [Today]".

Answer (score 1):

Did you know:
Calculated Fields DO accept =Today()
then select the datea type as Date.
Tested and working:  You can use Today() in the DATEDIF function. Then select the formula output data type as expected, for example you can use number if the expected output is "D" for days.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/datedif-function-HA001160981.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store the current date. What you can do is use the current date to filter the results of a query.